# MATLAB style array initialization in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I wanted to initialize a large array in bash, preferably using MATLAB style array initialization. For e.g. I want something similar to following

## Declare an array with elements ranging from 0 to 1000 with the gap of 5

```
array=0:5:1000
```

I know you can achieve that in a for loop as following

```
for i in {0..1000..5}
do
done
```

But same does not work in the following case

```
array={0..1000..5}

syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..1000..5}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make an array assignment, you need to wrap the brace expansion in `()`.

```
array=({0..1000..5})
```